# Test XMPP Camel route with Pidgin

Tags: java, xmpp, apache-camel

I've got, what I think, is a working Camel route in Java and I'm trying to confirm that it is sending messages.  I was hoping I could use Pidgin to confirm this.  Camel is running within ServiceMix.

The Camel route looks very similar to this (from [the apache site](http://camel.apache.org/xmpp.html)):

```
from("timer://kickoff?period=10000").
setBody(constant("I will win!\n Your Superman.")).
to("xmpp://superman@jabber.org/joker@jabber.org?password=secret");
```

where superman and joker are respective usernames and 'jabber.org' is replaced with my local IP where I have OpenFire running.  I had hoped a message window would pop up from Pidgin with the message text but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this an appropriate way to test my route or should I consider an alternative mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I noticed a plugin called "Monitoring Service" and installed it.  I'm seeing messages passing between users now.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with XMPP so might not be of a big help but first thing I would do is to [enable tracing](http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) in Camel to see what exactly is happening. More often than not it could give you at least a clue why it doesn't work.